# Updating a map in Android (Material Design)

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface

I have a Map which I place pins on to show certain locations -- the pins change with time. So like with a `ListView` that has content which changes, I was going to implement a "Swipe to refresh" so that users can swipe up to refresh the map to show new content.

But material design guidelines say:

> Pannable content, like in maps, have no primary direction or content origin from which users can presume the swipe to refresh gesture will originate.

That makes sense, but then what would be the best way to update the content of a Map in terms of UI (using Google Maps API if that matters)? I'm looking for a solution similar to swipe to refresh where users can fetch the new content from the server whenever they want.

--

If it matters, for context my Map is in a tab (using `ViewPager`) and the user can access it any time by swiping left/right to it.

Comment: Try to add refresh label over the map at top or bottom to manually update map content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could be really creative about it!

***Shake to refresh***

That way you don't need any interaction with the screen, which ideally should be dedicated to interactions with the map. You could tweak the responsiveness of the shake to whatever you want.

Or, you could use a traditional button somewhere on the screen, but I think a shake could be quite cool!